# pagination of arraylist inside a bean (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a bean mapped to a table (using hibernate).This bean contains an `ArrayList` of another mapped bean. It has a many to many relation mapping with cascade all. What I want to achieve is to paginate the data from this `ArrayList` using Criteria of the first bean?

Comment: do you want something like cascading dropdowns?

Comment: i need to paginate the data inside the list.
Class A
{
List<B> bList;
}
have criteria on A ,but have to paginate the data in the list.both the classes are mapped.

Comment: Does that mean you have exactly one entity of class A? Cause pagination can only be done on the parent class without native query or limiting in java?

Comment: No, I have 2 entities A and B both are mapped to their respective tables . there is one to many relation between A and B. so when i retrieve A i get list of B. what i want to do is to limit that list or better put paginate that list. 
say when input is 2 then retrieve A with list having only 2 elements in that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to first retrieve A and then in a second query get B's of A and use Query#setMaxResults() for getting only the number of B's you want.

You can't limit the number of B's directly when retrieving A with this approach. You would either need to write a native query or limit the number of B's in java.